# Reading contents of buffer line by line

Tags: python, ctypes, readline

I have to parse contents of printfbuf line by line, how can I do it?
I tried the following code but it prints one character per one line:

```
import StringIO
import ctypes

printbuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(100000)
print_buff = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(printbuffer))

buf = StringIO.StringIO(print_buff)
for x in buf.readline():
    print(x)
```

Comment: Try `readlines()`

Comment: You don't need `print_buff`, use `printbuffer.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `readlines` (plural), not `readline`.
`readline` reads one line and returns it (so you wind up iterating over the characters in a string, one at a time), while `readlines` returns each line of the file, one after another.
Line-by-line iteration is the default for file objects (and StringIO objects), so you could just use

```
for x in buf:
    print(x)  # you may want to print x[:-1] to avoid extra newlines
```